# How do I override HMENU Special setting based on layout?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I have a menu element that is set to list the selected pages.

```
tt_content.my_menu {
    dataProcessing {
        10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
        10 {
            special = list
            special.value.field = pages
        }
    }
}
```

How can I change this to a directory of pages when a specific layout is set?

```
tt_content.my_menu {
    dataProcessing {
        10 {
            special {
                override = directory
                override.if.value = my-layout
                override.if.equals.field = layout
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if `MenuProcessor`? has `stdWrap` on its properties.

But it should be possible to define two processors, each with an `if`:

```
tt_content.my_menu {
    dataProcessing {
        10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
        10 {
            if {
                value = my-layout
                equals.field = layout
                negate = 1
            }
            special = list
            special.value.field = pages
        }
        20 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
        20 {
            if {
                value = my-layout
                equals.field = layout
            }
            special = directory
            special.value.field = pages
        }
    }
}
```